# Poor LSTM Performance with Keras on Time Series Data

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, time-series, lstm

I'm trying to construct a network that will predict a Boolean target.

The data provided to the network contains both categorical and numerical entries but has all ready been properly processed. The data I am working with is *Time Series* data with 84 fields and 310033 rows of data. All the data has been scaled to remain between 0 and 1. Ever row represents a second in the data.

I created a database, data, with a shape (310033, 60, 500) and the target vector is of shape (1000, 1). The Time Step dimension was defined to be 60 because that is the maximum full 60 min hours possible with the amount of data available.

Then I split data (X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test).

Is it okay to give a matrix like this to the lstm model and expect a good prediction (if the relationships are there)? Because I have very poor performance. From what I have seen, people give only a 1D or 2D data and they reshape their data after to give a 3D input to the lstm layer. Which is what I have done here.

Below is the Transformation code from 2D to 3D:

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(scaled, target, train_size=.7, shuffle = False) 

# Generate Lag time Steps 3D framework for LSTM - Currently in 2D Framework
# As required for LSTM networks, we must reshape the input data into N_samples x TimeSteps x Variables
hours = len(X_train)/3600
hours = math.floor(hours) #Find Most full 60-min-hours available in subset of data 
temp =[]
# Pull hours into the three dimensional field
for hr in range(hours, len(X_train) + hours):
    temp.append(scaled[hr - hours:hr, 0:scaled.shape[1]])
X_train = np.array(temp) #Export Train Features in (70% x Hours x Variables)

hours = len(X_test)/3600
hours = math.floor(hours) #Find Most full 60-min-hours available in subset of data 
temp =[]
# Pull hours into the three dimensional field
for hr in range(hours, len(X_test) + hours):
    temp.append(scaled[hr - hours:hr, 0:scaled.shape[1]])
X_test = np.array(temp) #Export Test Features in (30% x Hours x Variables)
```

Below is the Framework of the Model:

```
    model = Sequential()

    #Layer 1 - returns a sequence of vectors
    model.add(LSTM(128, return_sequences=True, 
                   input_shape=(X_train.shape[1], X_train.shape[2]))) 
    model.add(Dropout(0.15)) #15% drop out layer
    #model.add(BatchNormalization())

    #Layer 2
    model.add(LSTM(256, return_sequences=False))
    model.add(Dropout(0.15)) #15% drop out layer
    #model.add(BatchNormalization())

    #Layer 3 - return a single vector
    model.add(Dense(32))

    #Output of 2 because we have 2 classes
    model.add(Dense(2, activation= 'sigmoid'))

    # Define optimiser
    opt = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=1e-5, decay=1e-6)

    # Compile model
    model.compile(loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', # Mean Square Error Loss = 'mse'; Mean Absolute Error = 'mae'; sparse_categorical_crossentropy
                  optimizer=opt, 
                  metrics=['accuracy'])
history = model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=epoch, batch_size=batch, validation_data=(X_test, y_test), verbose=3, shuffle=False)
```

I have experimented with many different frameworks for the LSTM. Single layer, multilayer, a double LSTM layer with 2 truncating Dense layers (LSTM -> LSTM -> Dense(32) -> Dense(2)), Batch normalization, etc...

Is there a suggested framework for this type of time series data to improve performance? I was getting better results when the data only had a single TimeStep = 1.

Comment: `sigmoid` is not correct, you need `softmax` in the last layer.

Comment: @Frightera - Thank you for your input I will give that a try. The reason I had done `sigmoid` is to squeeze my output between 0 and 1 similar to the input.  I followed this thought process because `sigmoid` is equivalent to a 2-element `softmax`.

Comment: Exactly, you need either 1 neuron activated by sigmoid or 2 neurons with softmax.